# How to convert normal sql query to Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-select

Hi I want to convert my normal mysql query to zend.db.select;

I want to use this script:

```
$select = $db->select();

// Add a FROM clause
$select->from( ...specify table and columns... )

// Add a WHERE clause
$select->where( ...specify search criteria... )

// Add an ORDER BY clause
$select->order( ...specify sorting criteria... );

$select->limit(20, 10);
```

**for my query below**

```
SELECT 
    IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, 
    derived_messages.toid) friend1,c.UserName,
    derived_messages.message, derived_messages.fromid, derived_messages.toid,
    derived_messages.is_read,derived_messages.type,derived_messages.id as mesid,                    
    derived_messages.date,
    (SELECT M.message_id FROM messagesmapped M where M.message_id= derived_messages.id AND M.user_id ='$user' AND M.important = 1) as MesMapid
    FROM 
    (               
    SELECT * 
    FROM messages
    WHERE messages.deleted_by NOT 
    IN ( $user ) 
    ORDER BY Date DESC      
    ) derived_messages
    INNER JOIN Users c ON c.MemberID = IF(derived_messages.toid = '$user', derived_messages.fromid, 
    derived_messages.toid)
    WHERE (derived_messages.id IN 
    (SELECT M.message_id FROM messagesmapped M where M.message_id= derived_messages.id AND M.user_id ='$user' AND M.important = 1)                  
    AND 
    (derived_messages.toid='$user' OR derived_messages.fromid='$user'))

    GROUP BY friend1 ASC 
    ORDER BY derived_messages.date DESC, derived_messages.id DESC LIMIT $limit $offset
```

I hope someone can help m on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible but unlikely someone will write the query for you.

My recommendation on tackling such a query is to write each individual subquery as its own `Zend_Db_Select` object and then build the final query using the subqueries that you already have objects for.

`Zend_Db_Select` doesn't directly support the `IF` function, so for that you will need to use [`Zend_Db_Expr`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr) to add that statement into your select.

---

Here is a basic example of what I am talking about.  Let's build the following query:

```
SELECT IF(msg.toId = 'drew010', msg.fromId, msg.toId), id, name, age, history.ip
FROM users
JOIN history ON users.id = history.userId
WHERE users.id = (
    SELECT id FROM users WHERE loginCount > 1000
)
GROUP BY id,
ORDER BY age DESC
```

First build the subselect that select users where `loginCount` > 1000.

```
$subquery1 = $db->select()
                ->from('users', array('id'))
                ->where('loginCount > ?', 1000);
```

Next, build the outer query with the IF function:

```
$cols  = array(
    new Zend_Db_Expr('IF(' . $db->quoteInto('msg.toId = ?', 'drew010') . '), msg.fromId, msg.toId'),
    'id', 'name', 'age'
);

$query = $db->select()
            ->from('users', $cols)
            ->join('history', 'users.id = history.userId', array('ip'))
            ->where('id = ?', $subquery1)
            ->group('id')
            ->order('age DESC');

echo $query;
```

The output:

```
SELECT
  IF(msg.toId = 'drew010', msg.fromId, msg.toId),
  `users`.`id`,
  `users`.`name`,
  `users`.`age`,
  `history`.`ip`
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `history`
  ON users.id = history.userId
WHERE id = (
    (SELECT `users`.`id`
    FROM `users`
    WHERE (loginCount > 1000))
)
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `age` DESC
```

---

So the way to go is break the entire query into individual queries first, and then construct the outer query.  Just have patience and take it slow.  That and read over the [`Zend_Db_Select`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) docs to get a full picture of what you have available to you.